# GCP Cloud Build via trigger: Dockerfile not found

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, gitlab, cicd, google-cloud-build

I attempt to trigger building a Docker image on GCP Cloud Build via webhook called from Gitlab. The webhook works, but the build process stops when I run `docker build` with this error:

`unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /workspace/Dockerfile: no such file or directory`

The YAML for this step is:

```yaml
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    args:
      - build
      - '-t'
      - '${_ARTIFACT_REPO}'
      - .
```

where I later supply the variable `_ARTIFACT_REPO` via `substitutions`.

My Gitlab repo includes the Dockerfile on the root level. So the repo structure is:

```
app/
.gitignore
Dockerfile
README.md
requirements.txt
```

The error message indicates that the Dockerfile cannot be found, but I do not understand why this is the case. Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Just solved the issue:

I followed the GCP docs ([link](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/automating-builds/gitlab/build-repos-from-gitlab)) where they include these two steps in the cloudbuild:

```yaml
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/git
  args:
    - clone
    - '-n'
    - 'git@gitlab.com/GITLAB_REPO'
    - .
  volumes:
    - name: ssh
      path: /root/.ssh
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/git
  args:
    - checkout
    - $_TO_SHA
```

As I did not require a specific checkout, I deleted the second step of those but I overlooked the `-n` flag in the first step that prevents checking out the cloned repo.

So I just deleted the `- '-n'` and issue solved.